# CouchDB::Client user/passwords

Tags: perl, couchdb

I'm trying to use the CouchDB::Client API for Perl.  I want to access a database on some server that hosts couchdb.  To access local databases with no access controls this is simple:

```
my $client = CouchDB::Client->new('localhost', '5984');
my $conn = $client->testConnection; 
print "client: $client \n"; 
print "connx : $conn \n";
```

But how does one do this for a remote host with access controls?  I don't see any option for a password in the CouchDB::Client file .... I need to use Perl for this rather than any other language, maybe there's another API that is more suited that I haven't come across?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you can include username and password into the http url like :-

```
CouchDB::Client->new(uri=>'http://YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_PASSWORD@localhost:5984/');
```

You can do a simple test with curl :-

```
curl -X HEAD http://USER:PASS@localhost/_active_tasks
// required authentication
```